# kibana/elasticsearch filter for "all records with the maximum value in field"

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, timestamp, kibana

I'm looking for a filter for an kibana visualization that will select only records having the maximum value in a specific field.*

In my case it's a timestamp field, so that only the most recent records are returned. It's a manually set field and all records generated by each run of an external process will have the same timestamp. I want the records from the most recent run.

This will be combined with other filters. So, e.g.,

```
"all documents with the largest value for the @timestamp field and {"term":{"color":"red"}}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can search for color:red in Search Bar present in Discover page. It will return results which you can sort by the largest values for @timestamp field.

Comment: This is for a dashboard visualization element, and needs to be canned. The visualization needs to only include documents with the latest timestamp.